# Cómo usar dos CASE en una consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy realizando un informe PDF en PHP.

El problema está en que en la base de datos se guardan valores enteros, porque así lo programé. El valor 1 sea igual a Pendiente, 2 En proceso y 3 terminado.

Cuando hago la consulta para extraer los valores en mi PDF me trae los valores enteros. Lo que quiero hacer es que en mi PDF me muestre los nombres a lo que corresponde.

Logré implementar en la columna `estado`, pero en `cuadrilla` no logro implementarlo. Quiero saber cómo realizar un segundo CASE, o de qué forma hacerlo para poder traer el nombre que corresponda.

[image: Captura de pantalla de la consulta SQL]

[image: Captura de pantalla del resultado actual en el informe]

```js
SELECT *, 
(case
WHEN estado=1 THEN 'Pendiente'
WHEN estado=2 THEN 'En proceso'
WHEN estado=3 THEN 'Terminado'
ELSE 'NO HAY DATOS' END) as estados
FROM sanandre_cmaps.reportes;
```

Comment: es exactamente igual... aunque deberias tenes una tabla con esos datos y joinearla...

Comment: Joinearla... * se muere de indignación * xD Por favor, algo de consideración con los cegatones y los que leemos desde el móvil: las consultas, los errores y los datos de prueba se ven mejor como texto siempre.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el SQL en texto en vez de en captura de pantalla? Además, también nos vendría bien saber la asociación que debería tener el campo "Cuadrilla". La solución es sencilla, pero necesitamos saber eso para poder ayudarte.

Comment: SELECT *, 
(case
WHEN estado=1 THEN 'Pendiente'
WHEN estado=2 THEN 'En proceso'
WHEN estado=3 THEN 'Terminado'
ELSE 'NO HAY DATOS' END) as estados
FROM sanandre_cmaps.reportes;

Comment: ¿Y qué hay de la asociación de la "Cuadrilla"? ¿Tenemos que inventarnosla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es sencilla, basta con agregar un nuevo `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE
        WHEN estado=1 THEN 'Pendiente'
        WHEN estado=2 THEN 'En proceso'
        WHEN estado=3 THEN 'Terminado'
        ELSE 'NO HAY DATOS'
    END estados,
    CASE
        WHEN cuadrilla=1 THEN 'Cuadrilla 1'
        WHEN cuadrilla=2 THEN 'Cuadrilla 2'
        WHEN cuadrilla=3 THEN 'Cuadrilla 3'
        WHEN cuadrilla=4 THEN 'Cuadrilla 4'
        WHEN cuadrilla=5 THEN 'Cuadrilla 5'
        WHEN cuadrilla=6 THEN 'Cuadrilla 6'
        ELSE 'Cuadrilla desconocida'
    END cuadrillas
FROM sanandre_cmaps.reportes
```

Te recomiendo identar el código SQL para entender y modificar con facilidad el código.

Aún así te recomiendo que este tipo de valores los almacenes en una tabla independiente y los relaciones a través de `JOIN`. Te permitirá más flexibilidad a la hora de agregar o quitar valores.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Ya quedo solucionado.